# What is the function of the following lines at the top of a shell script file: Directory: <directory path> ans Script: <script name>?

Tags: linux, shell

The file starts like this:

```
Directory: <path to the script>
Script: <script fife name>

#!bin/ksh

##Comments

<actual script>
```

What is the use of the first two lines in the script? What if I save the file without them? What will be the effect? They are not comments. 
Im very new to this, please help!

Comment: #!bin/ksh has no effect unless it is the first line in the script.  I think those lines are supposed to be removed and are just there to tell you where to put the script and what to call it.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 1):

At least in `bash` and `ksh` this your script will show errors :

**bash:**

```
./37018492.sh: line 1: Directory:: command not found
./37018492.sh: line 2: Script:: command not found
```

**ksh:**

```
main.ksh[1]: Directory:/home/cg/root: not found [No such file or directory]                                                                           
main.ksh[2]: Script:main.ksh: not found [No such file or directory]
```

**Conclusion**

Somebody might have forgotten to put the `#` before `Directory` & `Script`

**Edit**

The first `line/set of lines` of the script can be a `comment/set of comments`

```
#This is a comment
#This is another comment
```

or a shebang, say

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
```

The shebang's use comes when the script is executed directly say

```
./myscript
```

In this case the above shebang will give the same effect as

```
/usr/bin/ksh myscript
```

and when this happens the entire shebang line is ignored/treated as a comment by the interpreter.

Comment: My ksh version is `Version AJM 93u+` and is an emulator

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have removed these lines from my code. But I see working scripts which have them. Its strange though, because I do get the error of no such file or directory for these lines. 

Thanks a lot!